# How to get the current font size of an UILabel

Tags: ios, fonts, uilabel

I have adjusted the `UILabel` font size according to the width in this way.

```
[btnPending.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:15]];
[btnPending setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
btnPending.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
btnPending.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
btnPending.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping;
[_vwTabBtnParent addSubview:btnPending];
```

And its working fine. But now I want to get the current font size of that `UILabel`. How can I do this in objective-c.

Please help me,
Thanks

Comment: Have you found a solution to this question? I'm have the same issue and couldn't find a solution yet

Answer (score 4):

Then to get the font name and size all you need is

```
NSString *fontName = self.label.font.fontName;
CGFloat fontSize = self.label.font.pointSize;
```

Comment: this not return the current font size, it just return the 15. but it has shrinked according to the width

Comment: @user1960169 use this line of code after .number of lines =1;

Comment: yeas I used it after all those above lines

Comment: what the font size you gave and what you got as the result from this line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104409/discussion-between-kishore-kumar-and-user1960169).

Comment: cell.lblDisplay.numberOfLines=0;
//    cell.lblDisplay.clipsToBounds=YES;
    cell.lblDisplay.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
    cell.lblDisplay.clipsToBounds=YES;
    NSLog(@"this is point size %f",cell.lblDisplay.font.pointSize);

Answer (score 0):

Try below method:

```
[label.text sizeWithFont:label.font
             minFontSize:label.minimumFontSize
          actualFontSize:&actualFontSize
                forWidth:label.bounds.size.width
           lineBreakMode:label.lineBreakMode];
```

**Note:** Deprecated in iOS 7 with no alternative.

Comment: yeah I also found this,, but if its depricated how can we use it?